# Wrong Figma scale on 4K monitor

Tags: resize, resolution, figma

I have a Win10 on 3840×2160 screen with 200% system scale. Working in Figma I have all the designs shown noticeably larger so I got original size at 90%  zoom level. The same situation is in presentation mode and also in browser version of Figma. Only switching display to full HD (with system compatibility, for example) removes that extra 10% zoom.

Any tips to solve this annoyance?

Answer (score 0):

You can change interface scale in the [Desktop app](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049549913-Adjust-UI-scale-in-the-desktop-app) or simply the [page zoom](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96810?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) in the browser, but that would also change the size of texts and other interface elements, not only the canvas.